# How to check if a file exists in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am using makefile to build my program in multiple system. Some system have installed `colorgcc` script. In my Makefile i want to check, if script exists
and depending on it i setting up CC variable. But my Makefile don't work correctly - in system, that haven't colorgcc, `make` always set `$(CC)` as `colorgcc`. Here's part of Makefile:

```Makefile
ifneq ("$(wildchar /usr/bin/colorgcc)","") 
CC=colorgcc
else
CC=gcc
endif
```

I also tried to use this variant:

```Makefile
ifeq ( $(shell test -e /usr/bin/colorgcc), ) 
CC=colorgcc
else
CC=gcc
endif
```

In both case $(CC) doesn't depend of existence file /usr/bin/colorgcc

How can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you mistyped the function `$(wildcard ...)` so you get nothing, always.

In the second case, the output of `test` is always the empty string.  It will set its exit code depending on whether the condition is true or not, but you are not examining its exit code, just the output it prints, which will always be nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks! wildcard method now works. And also i fix test method so they also give correct result:

`ifeq ("$(shell test -e /usr/bin/colorgcc && echo ex)","ex")`